# conda env is forced to downgrade python version when using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, functools

I created an environment in Anaconda Navigator and indicated python version as 3.6.4. After the `env` has completed, I installed `matplotlib`, `numpy` and so on, but when I was running Jupyter Notebook on a browser, it's shown the python version - `Python 2`, like the screenshot shown:
[image]

Then, I checked what I installed in this environment in Anaconda Navigator, it's really shown that python version is `2`. So I was trying to upgrade python version to 3.6.4, then it's prompted that as shown below, complaining: `functools32` and `python 3.6.4` can not be satisfied and in conflict.

Then I searched google what is `functools32`, the result is a dependency of `matplotlib`
[image]

I'm looking forward to get an answer from you. Thanks In Advance.

- Updated: April 1st

As the screenshot shown, it hinted to me that Python will downgrade from 3.x to 2.x when I was trying to install `PIL`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you think you created an environment with Python 3.6.4 but the environment actually has Python 2.x then either you made a mistake while creating the environment, or you aren't actually using the environment you created, or one of the packages you installed after creating the environment forced a downgrade from 3.6.4 to 2.x (and I'm not sure if that's even possible).

If you open an Anaconda prompt and type

```
conda create -n new-env-name python=3.6.4 matplotlib
```

(where `new-env-name` is the name you want for your environment) then `conda` will show you what packages and what versions it is going to install in order to satisfy the dependencies of `matplotlib`. When I try this it lists Python 3.6.4 (as I asked) and `matplotlib` 2.2.2, but doesn't mention `functools32`.

I would try creating your environment from the command prompt as above, and then make sure this environment is actually the active one before using it.

Comment: You're right. matplotlib is not the main problem. But later, I found that it's `PIL` did. Look up above, I added a screenshot. I wanted to install `PIL`, but it hinted downgrading python version.

Comment: Looking at [PYPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL) and [the PIL home page](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), I don't think PIL was ever updated to Python 3.

Comment: I don't know what happened. But one solution is completely working, to create a new environment and install those modules what I need. Thank you! @nekomatic